# When to use scala.concurrent.blocking?

Tags: scala, concurrency, io, blocking, executioncontext

I am asking myself the question: "When should you use `scala.concurrent.blocking`?"

If I understood correctly, the `blocking {}` only makes sense to be used in conjunction with the ForkJoinPool. In addition [docs.scala-lang.org](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#the-global-execution-context) highlights, that blocking shouldn't be used for long running executions:

> Last but not least, you must remember that the ForkJoinPool is not designed for long-lasting blocking operations.

I assume a long running execution is a database call or some kind of external IO. In this case a separate thread pools should be used, e.g. CachedThreadPool. Most IO related frameworks, like sttp, doobie, cats can make use of a provided IO thread pool.

So I am asking myself, which use-case still exists for the blocking statement? Is this only useful, when working with locking and waiting operations, like semaphores?

Comment: What `blocking` does is precisely tell the runtime to take away that blocking operation out of the EC into its own separated thread so that it doesn't hurt that much the performance. - And no, those libraries don't create their own thread pools, those libraries will run in the runtime you tell them to run, **cats-effect** providing one extremely optimized runtime for the `IO` data type that handles blocking operations better than what `blocking` does for `Future`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez. When I said "build on top" I meant using a (provided) thread pool. But again, the question is more about the ForkJoinPool. Should you use a separate thread for IO blocking or work with blocking {} and a ForkJoinPool. Scala-lang recommends not to use blocking for long-lasting blocking. So the question still remains: What is a long-lasting blocking?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the problem of thread pool *starvation*. Say you have a fixed size thread pool of 10 available threads, something like so:

```
implicit val myFixedThreadPool = 
  ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))
```

If for some reason all 10 threads are tied up, and a new request comes in which requires an 11th thread to do its work, then this 11th request will hang until one of the threads becomes available.

`blocking { Future { ... } }` construct can be interpreted as saying please do not consume a thread from `myFixedThreadPool` but instead spin up a new thread outside `myFixedThreadPool`.

One practical use case for this is if your application can conceptually be considered to be in two parts, one part which say in 90% of cases is talking to proper async APIs, but there is another part which in few special cases has to talk to say a very slow external API which takes many seconds to respond and which we have no control over. Using the fixed thread pool for the true async part is relatively safe from thread pool starvation, however also using the same fixed thread pool for the second part presents the danger of the situation where suddenly 10 requests are made to the slow external API, which now causes 90% of other requests to hang waiting for those slow requests to finish. Wrapping those slow requests in `blocking` would help minimise the chances of 90% of other requests from hanging.

Another way of achieving this kind of "swimlaning" of true async request from blocking requests is by offloading the blocking request to a separate dedicated thread pool to be used just for the blocking calls, something like so

```
implicit val myDefaultPool = 
  ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))

val myPoolForBlockingRequests = 
  ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20))

Future { 
  callAsyncApi    
}                                  // consume thread from myDefaultPool 
...
Future { 
  callBlockingApi 
}(myPoolForBlockingRequests)      // consume thread from myPoolForBlockingRequests
```

Comment: As I understood, the blocking only works with the ForkJoinPool. Did I understood this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

> I am asking myself the question: "When should you use scala.concurrent.blocking?"

Well, since that is mostly useful for `Future` and `Future` should never be used for serious business logic then never.

Now, *"jokes"* aside, when using `Futures` then you should always use `blocking` when wrapping blocking operations, AND receive a custom `ExecutionContext`; instead of hardcoding the `global` one. Note, this should always be the case, even for non-blocking operations, but IME most folks using `Future` don't do this... but that is another discussion.

Then, callers of those blocking operations may decide if they will use their compute EC or a blocking one.
When the docs mention long-lasting they don't mean anything specific, mostly because is too hard to be specific about that; is context / application specific. What you need to understand is that `blocking` by default *(note the actual EC may do whatever they want)* will just create a new thread, and if you create a lot of threads and they take too long to be released you will saturate your memory and kill the program with an OOM error.

For those situations, the recommendation is to control the back pressure of your app to avoid creating too many threads. One way to do that is to create a fixed thread pool for the maximum number of blocking operations you will support and just enqueue all other pending tasks; such EC should just ignore `blocking` calls. You may also just have an unbound number of threads but manage the back pressure manually in other parts of your code; e.g. with an explicit `Queue`, this was common advice before: https://gist.github.com/djspiewak/46b543800958cf61af6efa8e072bfd5c

However, having blocked threads is always hurtful for the performance of your app, even if the compute EC is not blocked. The latest talks by Daniel explain those in detail: "The case for effect systems" & "Threads at scale".
So the ecosystem is pushing hard the state of the art to avoid that at all costs but is not a simple task. Still, runtimes like the ones provided by **cats-effect** or **ZIO** are optimized to handle blocking tasks the best they can as of today, and will probably improve during this and next years.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome video recommendation. The video of [Daniel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgfCmQ-2tW0) is super interesting!